# Inequalities : $0<a,b,c<1$. Prove that not all three of $a(1-b), b(1-c)$ and $c(1-a)$ can be greater than $\frac 14$

Tags: inequality

The only idea that I got in regard with this question was that for the given condition to be satisfied, the product of $a(1-b)$, $b(1-c)$ and $c(1-a)$ must be smaller than $\frac 14$. But it didn't seem to be very helpful.

Comment: Duplicate, I saw it yesterday or so. Assume the contrary, and multiply the three together. You get a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Assume by contradiction that $a(1-b) > 1/4, b(1-c) > 1/4, c(1-a) > 1/4$. Then, by AM-GM we have

$$\frac{1}{2} < \sqrt{a(1-b)} \leq \frac{a+1-b}{2}$$
$$\frac{1}{2} < \sqrt{b(1-c)} \leq \frac{b+1-c}{2}$$
$$\frac{1}{2} < \sqrt{c(1-a)} \leq \frac{c+1-a}{2}$$

Adding together we get

$$\frac{3}{2} < \mbox{junk} \leq \frac{3}{2} $$

contradiction.